# How do I get the checked row data to pass into another datatable via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get the checked row data but I got no idea how can I pass it from on submit function. So I can pass the data to another `php` `datatable` and how I can retrieve the data once I pass it over?

```
$('#submit_form').on('submit', function(){
    //function to get the checkbox that is checked data and pass it to another php
});
```

My html table

```
<form id="submit_form" action="<?php echo site_url('Test_product/import');?>">
<p align="right"><button name="import" type="submit" form="submit_form">Import </button></p>
<table id="import" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input name="select" id="select" type="checkbox" checked></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            </table>
            </form>
```

My ajax

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('#import').DataTable({

        bProcessing: true,
        ajax: "localhost/product.php",
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'id',
                searchable: false,
                orderable: false,
                className: 'dt-body-center',
                render: function (data, type, full, meta){
                return '<input type="checkbox" name="' +data+ '"'+ 'checked>'; }
            },
            {data: 'photo'},
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'sku'}
            ]
        });

        $('#select').on('click', function(){
          // Get all rows with search applied
          var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
          // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
          $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $('#submit_form').on('submit', function(){
            var data = table.rows(this).data();
            alert(data[0]);
        });

});
</script>
```

My json output

```
{"data":[{"id":35,"name":"_testing_product_009","sku":"-","photo":""}]}
```

Comment: because I want to pass the data to another php file.

Comment: show the html of your table and a row

Comment: ok I have done editing it.

Comment: Ok so now what exactly would you want to have as your desired result? It seems to me that the output you're posting is the row data you're describing in your post

Comment: my main is to pass the row data to another php file, example test.php so that I can print out the datatable on test.php